# terminal can't see copied folder - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, openfoam

I am really new to Ubuntu and OpenFoam, so trying to learn and doing some tutorials. I am using Docker to work with OpenFoam on Ubuntu.

I copied a folder to a specific directory, however when I try to access that folder using the terminal, I can't; I only see the original folder, not the copied.

I have used commands such as `cd` to go to the directory and `ls` to see what folders are present, and that's where I only see the original folder.

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: nvm, the problem is I can't seem to find OpenFoam installation folder in /opt or anywhere but the home directory, which seems to be missing loads of files

Comment: This seems more appropriate for https://askubuntu.com as StackOverflow is for programming related QA

Comment: Are you able to see the folder in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/` directory? You can run a simple `find` command to check the folder in above directory. If it is present, you should be able to check the folder in container. If not, you could logoff and logon to docker shell and try.

Comment: hi @harshavmb , doesn't seem to have a folder aufs

Comment: ok, i figured out a bit, and seems like docker should have /opt/openfoam folder somewhere, how would i access it? or how would i access any folder that docker contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ls -la to see all folder or files.
And check the owner and rights on this folder.

Comment: thank you, i seem to be getting lost  in the directories. finally found where i was meant to be

Comment: @Ana Please, accept the answer if the answer is fine.